# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero que después de elevar cada elemento de la lista al cuadrado que ya lo hice, se puedan sumar todos después, que ahí es donde me sale error.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
x = (success_estimates['Jamaica'])
for i in x:
    print(' c ')
    z=i**2
    sum((a) for a in z)
```

Y éste es el error que recibo:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-228-af93bd0f165f> in <module>
      3     print(' c ')
      4     z=i**2
----> 5     sum((a) for a in z)

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que es lo que tratabas de hacer?

Comment: La pregunta estaba mejor cuando no tenías el código en una imagen. Si te niegas a adherirte a las reglas de SOes (que @gbianchi te ha puesto en su comentario por cierto), votaré para que la pregunta sea cerrada. Por favor edítala siguiendo las normas!

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con tu código,

```
z=i**2
```

la variable `z` contiene un valor numérico (`float`, para ser precisos).

Las variables tipo `float` no pueden ser iteradas; no tiene sentido. Puedes iterar un string, pero no un valor numérico. De ahi el error.

El resto del código tampoco hace mucho sentido:

```
sum((a) for a in z)
```

es lo mismo que decir

```
sum(z)
```

La verdad, no se entiende que quieres lograr con tu código, y por tanto, no se puede ofrecer una solución.

Comment: Hay una lista que dice jamaica con numero.. 0.2, 0.4... quiero hacer esto [Jamaica, 1.2987] (since 1.2987 = 0.61^2 + 0.65^2 + 0.71^2) pero con list comprehensions.

Osea qme salen para sumar los valores pero cuando los elevo a la dos no me deja, y no quiero hacerlos por cada valor. y cuando los elevo que fue donde los hice y despues de elevar los valores a la 2 me sale ese error al sumarlos.

Comment: @DictaDavidDream y porque en lugar de arruinar tu pregunta, poniendo como imagen el codigo y sin explicar nada, ponias todo eso en tu pregunta para entender que tratabas de hacer?

Comment: Lo siento, no me supe explicar, pense que al ver la imagen me podrian entender.

Comment: quiero que despues de elevarlos al cuadrado se puedan sumar solo eso, no se si es posible.

Comment: @DictaDavidDream agrega toda esta informacion en la pregunta.. con el codigo!!!